# Tortoise SVN automatic merge - disable doesn't work

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In my company we are using TortoiseSVN with automatic merges turned off this way( http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#noautomerge ). But when I am merging range of revision(feature branch), Tortoise do automatic merges, despite my setting. During Update automatic merge correctly fails as I expected.
Tortoise version, merge tool setup, diff tool setup are in attachement.
Please help me.
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: added [helpers] section of SVN config file

```
### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor-cmd to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
###   et al).
# editor-cmd = editor (vi, emacs, notepad, etc.)
### Set diff-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff implementation.
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
diff-cmd = "C:\\SVNNoMerge.bat" 
diff3-cmd = "C:\\SVNNoMerge.bat"
### Diff-extensions are arguments passed to an external diff
### program or to Subversion's internal diff implementation.
### Set diff-extensions to override the default arguments ('-u').
# diff-extensions = -u -p
### Set diff3-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff3' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff3 implementation.
# diff3-cmd = diff3_program (diff3, gdiff3, etc.)
### Set diff3-has-program-arg to 'yes' if your 'diff3' program
###   accepts the '--diff-program' option.
# diff3-has-program-arg = [yes | no]
### Set merge-tool-cmd to the command used to invoke your external
### merging tool of choice. Subversion will pass 5 arguments to
### the specified command: base theirs mine merged wcfile
# merge-tool-cmd = merge_command
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the false.bat file for the `diff3-cmd`, not just the `diff-cmd` part as stated in the FAQ.

Comment: I have this(I added helpers section of config file to original post)

Comment: can you please help me? I do not know how to solve problem myself.